# How to draw a compass

Tags: kotlin

Good day, everyone. Please, I am a novice in Android development and i am tasked with developing a GPS waypointing application with Kotlin. Please, can anyone tell me how I can achieve the drawing of this compass using onDraw methods and not image(I was asked not to use Image). The link here  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oTXM.jpg.shows the compass I need to replicate, but I don't know how to go about it. Please, I would be grateful to also welcome suggestions on how I can develop this application.

Comment: Why can't you use an image, rotate it and draw the blue line and the text over it?

Comment: This question is too big for this site. You need to at least read the documentation on how to use Canvas and then ask about what you're stuck on. Otherwise you're asking someone to repeat all the documentation for you and/or spend hours doing your task for you.